Laravel PestUnit - Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 200
I'm trying to use the Pest PHP framework for testing, but I'm unable to perform a simple test.
it('can view home page', function () {
    $response = $this->get('/');

    expect($response->status())->toBe(200);
});

I always get the error:

Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 200.

It seems that the URL is not being correctly read. Here's my files configuration:
.env file
APP_NAME="My software name"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:abchdX+Hm/LYphNZIBx942SFZoJYzGUFGidCxQifqMw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost/mysoftware

phpunit.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="local"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>

I've read some topics such as:
https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/kivwyr/laravel_phpunit_test_pointing_to_wrong_url/
Configuring Laravel 5 Unit Test URL with phpunit.xml
Laravel phpunit not getting right url
Where I end up trying to rectify my phpunit.xml file by appending:
<env name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost/mysoftware"/>

But the error persists. What can I do to debug further?

Edit 1) - My routes files indeed have both / & /login routes and it doesn't matter if the test is pointing to home route or login route, the error is the same.
it('can view home page', function () {
    $response = $this->get('/');

    expect($response->status())->toBe(200);
});

it('can view login page', function () {
    $response = $this->get('/login');

    expect($response->status())->toBe(200);
});



is there a route in your route file that refers to / ?

Of course, I can access to http://localhost/mysoftware. The same error happens to http://localhost/mysoftware/login.

Solved.
Dunno why, but got it working by changing the .env file from this:
APP_URL=http://localhost/mysoftware

to this
APP_URL=http://localhost

No need to change the phpunit.xml file (at least in my case...)

Try to remove the config cache using this command :
php artisan config:cache

And try it with this config in your phpunit.xml:
<server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/>


I've done that. I even went further by performing cache:clear ; route:clear ; route:cache ;
config:clear ; config:cache

check the new update

Is that line suppose to be inside <php> tag? Anyway, tried inside & outside and still doesn't work. Tried instead of http://localhost to add http://localhost/mysoftware and the issue persists. Also cleared the cache everytime I changed the phpunit.xml file.

Yes inside <php> leave it like this <server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/> not <server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost/mysoftware"/>

No luck, doesn't work. I just inspected the $response through XDebug and the baseContent->response property shows my 404.blade.php page with all the links pointing to http://localhost/ instead of http://localhost/mysoftware.
